# download artifact from remote repository using java and aether

Tags: java, maven-3, artifactory, sonatype

Im trying to connect to a remote repository using java and aethor library, to download artifact i.e jar/zip/war manually through code. But im finding the documentation not very helpful, anybody got any ideas?

here is what i have

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
    DefaultServiceLocator locator = new DefaultServiceLocator();
    locator.addService( RepositoryConnectorFactory.class, AsyncRepositoryConnectorFactory.class );
    locator.addService( RepositoryConnectorFactory.class, WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory.class );
    locator.addService( VersionResolver.class, DefaultVersionResolver.class );
    locator.addService( VersionRangeResolver.class, DefaultVersionRangeResolver.class );
    locator.addService( ArtifactDescriptorReader.class, DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.class );
    locator.setServices( WagonProvider.class, new WagonProvider() {
        public Wagon lookup( String roleHint ) throws Exception {
            if( "http".equals( roleHint ) ) {
                return new LightweightHttpWagon();
            }
            return null;
        }

        public void release( Wagon wagon ) {}
    } );

    RepositorySystem system = locator.getService( RepositorySystem.class );

    MavenRepositorySystemSession session = new MavenRepositorySystemSession();

    LocalRepository localRepo = new LocalRepository( "target/local-repo" );
    session.setLocalRepositoryManager( system.newLocalRepositoryManager( localRepo ) );

    Artifact artifact = new DefaultArtifact( "junit:junit:4.8.2" );

    // RemoteRepository repo = new RemoteRepository("central", "default", "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/");
    Authentication authentication = new Authentication( "atestuser", "apassword" );
    RemoteRepository repo = new RemoteRepository( ).setUrl( "https://somerepository/repo/" ).setAuthentication( authentication );


    RepositoryConnector connector = new AsyncRepositoryConnectorFactory().newInstance( session, repo );

    ArtifactDownload artDown = new ArtifactDownload( artifact, null, new File("C:\\test\\junit.jar"), null );
    connector.get( Arrays.asList( artDown ), null );

    connector.close();

    ArtifactRequest artifactRequest = new ArtifactRequest();
    artifactRequest.setArtifact( artifact );
    artifactRequest.addRepository( repo );

    ArtifactResult artifactResult = system.resolveArtifact( session, artifactRequest );

    artifact = artifactResult.getArtifact();

    System.out.println( artifact + " resolved to  " + artifact.getFile() );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm also using eclipse aether to download artifacts. I find starting with eclipse aether is a bit harder than the older sonatype aether but here is a small sample project I have created as part of an open-source project: [MavenPP](https://github.com/shillner/MavenPP/tree/master/de.itemis.mpp.utils.aether)

There is also a nice demo project which shows many features of eclipse aether: [aether-demo](https://github.com/eclipse/aether-demo/tree/master/aether-demo-snippets/src/main/java/org/eclipse/aether/examples)

Hope this helped ;)

Comment: thanks will look at that. How about downloading a artifact from a repository that uses HTTPS,